# Как объединить вывод данных с значением false и если пустое?

Tags: php, mysql

Проблема в том что у меня в базе данных есть значение одного столбца, оно обычно `false`, но бывает случается что пустое, как мне при выводе объединить их в один вывод. Т.е. значений `false` 1000шт, а с пустым значением 230шт, объединить в Не определено 1230шт

сам запрос такой:

```
$source_p = mysql_query("select ST.utm_term, ST.hash_person, COUNT(ST.utm_term) AS `stat_count`, count(distinct L.id) AS `lids_count`, count(distinct LL.id) AS `clients_count`
FROM stat ST
    left join lids L on L.hash_person=ST.hash_person and L.id_cabinet = '$id_cabinet' $filtr_date_l and L.delete_status='0'
    left join leads_sort LS on LS.id_cabinet = $id_cabinet and LS.url = 'done'
    left join status S on LS.id_parameter = S.leadssort and S.id_cabinet = $id_cabinet
    left join lids LL on S.id = LL.status and LL.hash_person = ST.hash_person and L.id_cabinet = '$id_cabinet' $filtr_date_ll and LL.delete_status = '0'
WHERE ST.id_cabinet=$id_cabinet $filtr_date_st
GROUP BY
    `utm_term`
ORDER BY
    `clients_count`
DESC");
```

вот как объединить это

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавить в where `name_field` = 0 and `name_field` = 'false'

Comment: Не понял, у меня выводится таблица, выводит две строки Не определено и пустое... и что это такое where `` и куда это добавить

Comment: не прокатило! если так сделать он показывает всего одно поле

Comment: добавил картинку

Comment: Никак, делайте это прямо в приложении. Если вам критично получать верный результат из БД, то проапдейтьте один тип результатов, чтобы все были одинаковые.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно так (проверить нет возможности):
заменить

```
COUNT(ST.utm_term) AS `stat_count`
```

на

```
COUNT(IF(ST.utm_term = '', false, ST.utm_term)) AS `stat_count`
```

Comment: спасибо отличное решение